# Deleting isalpha out of function, causes it to return 0 all the time

Tags: c, string, pointers, palindrome, isalpha

I have to write a function to check for palindromes in sentences and words.

For sentences it looks like this (and works):

```
int checkSentencepalindrome(char * str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    
    char *pntr1 = str;
    char *pntr2 = str + len - 1;
    
    while(pntr2 >= pntr1)
    {
        if (!isalpha(*pntr2))
        {
            pntr2--;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (!isalpha(*pntr1))
        {
            pntr1++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(tolower(*pntr1) != tolower(*pntr2))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        pntr1++;
        pntr2--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

for word palindromes it looks like this:

```
int checkWordpalindrome(char * str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    
    char *pntr1 = str;
    char *pntr2 = str + len - 1;
    
    while(pntr2 >= pntr1)
    {
        if(tolower(*pntr1) != tolower(*pntr2))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        pntr1++;
        pntr2--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, the function for word palindromes returns me 0 all the time. (I expect a 1 for palindrome and 0 for non-palindrome words)

I thought the if statements I deleted are just there to skip spaces, exclamation marks, etc. (everything not included in the alphabet) Why are they so crucial for my function to work properly then?

How can I solve this while using pointers only?

EDIT: The issue only occurs when passing the string as following:

```
int checkWpalindrome(char * str)
{
    printf("%s ", str);
    
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    
    if(len == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char *pntr1 = str;
    char *pntr2 = str + len - 1;
    
    while(pntr2 >= pntr1)
    {
        if(tolower(*pntr1) != tolower(*pntr2))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        pntr1++;
        pntr2--;
    }
    return 1;
}

void input(char * str)
{
    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(str, 101, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
}

int main()
{
    char arr[10];
    
    input(arr);
    
    printf("%d", checkWpalindrome(arr));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine in general https://onlinegdb.com/ModQyqD7B Please give an example where it doesn't work as expected

Comment: You are right... I added an example.

Comment: @wolffsen Post input used.

Comment: Your `fgets` has a limit of 101 characters for input but the array your pass to it is only 10 characters in size. Also, `fflush` on an input stream is (generally) undefined behaviour.

Comment: But the main issue would appear to be that the string your are testing ***includes the newline at the end***.

Answer (score 0):

- `fgets()` includes reading and saving a `'\n'` and causes `checkWordpalindrome()` to return 0 (unless maybe only `"\n"` was read). [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716823/deleting-isalpha-out-of-function-causes-it-to-return-0-all-the-time/74717210#comment131871797_74716823).
- To lop off the potential `'\n'`, use `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` right after `fgets()`.
- Both functions risk *undefined behavior* (UB) as they can attempt to generate a pointer to *before* `str`.  Consider `check...("?")`.
- In `checkSentencepalindrome()` the UB is is more so as code then attempts `*pntr2` of an invalid pointer.
- `isalpha(ch)` and `tolower(ch)` have (UB) when `ch < 0` (and not `EOF`)
- Calling code buffer too small: `char arr[10]; ... fgets(str, 101, stdin);`.  Make them the same size like `char arr[101]; ... fgets(str, 101, stdin);`
- `fflush(stdin);` is UB and not needed. [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716823/deleting-isalpha-out-of-function-causes-it-to-return-0-all-the-time/74717210#comment131871743_74716823)

Repaired code:

```
int checkSentencepalindrome(const char * str) {
  size_t len = strlen(str);
    
  const unsigned char *left = (const unsigned char *) str;
  const unsigned char *right = left + len; // point one-past
    
  while(left < right) {
    if (!isalpha(right[-1])) {
      right--;
      continue;
    }
        
    if (!isalpha(left[0])) {
      left++;
      continue;
    }
        
    right--;
    if (tolower(left[0]) != tolower(right[0])) {
      return 0;
    }
    left++;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

---

A bit tidier with

```
  while(left < right) {
    if (!isalpha(*left)) {
      left++;
      continue;
    }

    right--;
    if (!isalpha(*right)) {
      continue;
    }
        
    if (tolower(*left) != tolower(*right)) {
      return 0;
    }
    left++;
  }
```

Comment: Tidied up my code using your recommendations. Thank you!